# How to correct mouse event in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, mouseevent, lazy-high-charts

I am trying to plot xy line in which y axis is reversed and I am getting plot but `mouse event` I am unable to correct it it is showing reverse event, and I want to find min and mix of axis automatically how this can be done? And how to bring x axis on top?

This is my code:

**JS**

```
$(function () {
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        zoomType: 'xy',
        marginLeft: 50,
        marginBottom: 90
    },

   // How to get minmax automatically zooming is a issue
   // reverse is true
    yAxis: {
        reversed: true,
        min:0,max:50
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            stacking: 'normal'
        }
    },

   series: [
           {
                   name: '01-Jan-2014',
                   data: [[30,0],[28,10]]
           }
           ]
});
});
```

**HTML**

```
  <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
  <div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Here is a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2xLvY/).

Whether its possible to pass string inside series ? may be my question is silly please tell me whether its possible, like below I am interested

```
   string mystring = "{
                 name: '01-Jan-2014',
                 data: [[28, 10],[30, 0]]
               },
               {
                 name: '01-Jan-2014',
                 data: [[28, 10],[30, 0]]
               }"
```

In series part of code I would like to do like below

```
                 series: [ 
                             mystring
                         ]
```

Expected output from this array, sorted y axis [GOOD PATTERN - Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F5NK8/) but mouse movement is not working

```
data:[
[ 25.290,1.000 ],
[ 25.240,2.000 ],
[ 25.210,3.000 ],
[ 25.190,4.000 ],
[ 25.180,5.000 ],
[ 25.170,6.000 ],
[ 25.160,7.000 ],
[ 25.310,8.000 ],
[ 25.210,9.000 ],
[ 25.170,10.000 ],
[ 25.160,11.000 ],
[ 25.160,12.000 ],
[ 25.150,13.000 ],
  ]
```

here I sorted xaxis - mouse event is alright but plot pattern (line) is not the one which  I expect [BAD PATTERN - Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b8FYH/)

```
   data:[
[ 25.150,13.000 ],
[ 25.160,12.000 ],
[ 25.160,11.000 ],
[ 25.160,7.000 ],
[ 25.170,6.000 ],
[ 25.170,10.000 ],
[ 25.180,5.000 ],
[ 25.190,4.000 ],
[ 25.210,9.000 ],
[ 25.210,3.000 ],
[ 25.240,2.000 ],
[ 25.290,1.000 ],
[ 25.310,8.000 ],
  ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers:

- you have errors in JS console - fix them (sort data ascending by x-value!)
- to set min and max, just don't set anything, Highcharts will calculate extremes
- to display xAxis on top, set `opposite: true`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2xLvY/1/

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        zoomType: 'xy',
        marginLeft: 50,
        marginBottom: 90
    },

    yAxis: {
        reversed: true,
        //min: 0,
        //max: 50
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            stacking: 'normal'
        }
    },
    xAxis: {
        opposite: true  
    },
    series: [{
        name: '01-Jan-2014',
        data: [
            // NOTE: proper order, first x-value is lower that second
            [28, 10],
            [30, 0]
        ]
    }]
});
```

Comment: +1 Pawel Fus, Thank you so much, you mean I have to sort data before inputing to javascript ? is there any function to sort array

Comment: Before using data for Highchart.

Comment: Is there any function to sort array in javascript ?

Comment: Of course, see [Array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Comment: Can you do one more help for me ? I want to send complete series data as string is it possible ?

Comment: It can't be string, sorry. If that string will be proper JSON, then you will be able to use `JSON.parse()` or `eval()`.

Comment: I am sorry to say if I sort x column complete plot pattern  is changing and result is not proper, in my original post I posted a new data sorted please have a look, mouse event is still not solved

Comment: Fus Did you see my problem ?

Comment: I have opened new thread if you have time please help me, sorting x axis won't help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22587836/highcharts-mouse-event-bug-in-line-chart

Comment: Man, relax, it was weekend :) Anyway - duplicated x-values OR unsorted data is **NOT** supported by Highcharts for line series. I advice to change to `scatter` type.