# BUG In Highchart's Mouse Event With Plot Type : Line / Spline

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, lazy-high-charts

It looks like there is some bug in mouse event tracking in highcharts line plot, I am not sure whether its bug or not, I have one more post on same matter here few days ago, [How to correct mouse event in Highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22524584/how-to-correct-mouse-event-in-highcharts), in which one of the engineers of highcharts support, suggested to sort x axis, I did the same as he suggested, but result is one which I can't accept in practical

Here is link to Fiddle, please look into it

1 ) Good pattern yaxis sorted mouse event not working ---> [Good](http://jsfiddle.net/F5NK8/)

```
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
    $(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    title: {
        text: 'Y axes reversed'
    },

    yAxis: {
        reversed: true  
    },        
    series: [{
         data:[
[ 25.290,1.000 ],
[ 25.240,2.000 ],
[ 25.210,3.000 ],
[ 25.190,4.000 ],
[ 25.180,5.000 ],
[ 25.170,6.000 ],
[ 25.160,7.000 ],
[ 25.310,8.000 ],
[ 25.210,9.000 ],
[ 25.170,10.000 ],
[ 25.160,11.000 ],
[ 25.160,12.000 ],
[ 25.150,13.000 ],
  ]      
    }]
});
});
```

2 ) Bad pattern xaxis sorted mouse event is working --->[Bad](http://jsfiddle.net/b8FYH/)

```
 <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
 <div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
$(function () {

$('#container').highcharts({
    title: {
        text: 'Y axes reversed'
    },
    xAxis :{opposite: true, },
    yAxis: {
        reversed: true  
    },        
    series: [{
        data:[
[ 25.150,13.000 ],
[ 25.160,12.000 ],
[ 25.160,11.000 ],
[ 25.160,7.000 ],
[ 25.170,6.000 ],
[ 25.170,10.000 ],
[ 25.180,5.000 ],
[ 25.190,4.000 ],
[ 25.210,9.000 ],
[ 25.210,3.000 ],
[ 25.240,2.000 ],
[ 25.290,1.000 ],
[ 25.310,8.000 ],
  ]
    }]
});
});
```

Please someone help me to solve issue, This is what I have tried so far [My Try on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/myH7b/) ,here you can see with same data **y axis sorted** with **scatter** plot mouse event is working but not working with line plot.

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        defaultSeriesType: 'scatter'
       },
title :{ 
        text:'overlap, scatter points on line for mouse events, trying to keep same color and legend so that mouse event might work, do not know how to do it'
        },

xAxis : { opposite : true },
yAxis : { reversed : true },
series: [{
name: '07-Jan-2006 07:30:00 AM' ,
data:[
[ 25.290,1.000 ],
[ 25.240,2.000 ],
[ 25.210,3.000 ],
[ 25.190,4.000 ],
[ 25.180,5.000 ],
[ 25.170,6.000 ],
[ 25.160,7.000 ],
[ 25.310,8.000 ],
[ 25.210,9.000 ],
[ 25.170,10.000 ],
[ 25.160,11.000 ],
[ 25.160,12.000 ],
[ 25.150,13.000 ],
  ]
  },{
 name: '07-Jan-2006 07:30:00 AM' ,
 type : 'line',
 marker: {enabled:false},
 enableMouseTracking: false,

 data:[
[ 25.290,1.000 ],
[ 25.240,2.000 ],
[ 25.210,3.000 ],
[ 25.190,4.000 ],
[ 25.180,5.000 ],
[ 25.170,6.000 ],
[ 25.160,7.000 ],
[ 25.310,8.000 ],
[ 25.210,9.000 ],
[ 25.170,10.000 ],
[ 25.160,11.000 ],
[ 25.160,12.000 ],
[ 25.150,13.000 ],
  ]
  }]
  });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to correct mouse event in Highcharts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22524584/how-to-correct-mouse-event-in-highcharts)

Comment: It's not a bug, read [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data). And duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22524584/how-to-correct-mouse-event-in-highcharts).

Comment: Hi! Pawel I mentioned that, I have one more post on same matter, I was suspecting that it could be bug so asked, highchart support team helped me...